# Problems while testing Yii application on Selenium?

Tags: php, selenium, yii

I'm using selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar for test my Yii application. I run it in the console without any parameters:
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
I have next problems:

1. Hangs Firefox.In consoles window where I run Selenium has text:
   Launching Firefox...
   In consoles window where I run tests nothing.
2. Unable to make a screenshot in Google Chrome.
   Exception: ERROR: captureEntirePageScreenshot is only implemented for Firefox ("firefox" or "chrome", NOT "firefoxproxy") and IE non-HTA ("iexploreproxy", NOT "iexplore" or "iehta"). The current browser isn't one of them!

My OS - Windows 8. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you show the configurations used?

Comment: `<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
  colors="false"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  stopOnFailure="false">

 <selenium>
  <browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox" />
 </selenium>
</phpunit>`

Comment: `<browser name="Chrome" browser="*googlechrome" /> `

for run tests in Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions to problems are found:

1. Under Windows 8 Firefox 19+ hangs. Version 17 works.
2. Creation of screenshots in Google Chrome is not currently possible. "chrome" in error message  - it's not Google Chrome. It's Firefox mode.